# Randomly generate from a database

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

So I have created a database in sqlite and using tkinter in python. I have managed to make a window that will allow the user to press  button that will randomly pick from this list however the list isn't randomly generating and is only picking the end item of the list from the database. This is my code so far.. any help?

```
from tkinter import
import random
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('cashflow.db')#creates database file
c = conn.cursor()
def tableCreate(): #creates the multiplechoice table 
    c.execute("CREATE TABLE multiplechoice(Equation VARCHAR, Answer VARCHAR)")
    conn.commit()


def dataEntry():  #Enters the equations in the table 
 c.execute("INSERT INTO multiplechoice VALUES('average selling price x goods sold','sales revenue')")
 c.execute("INSERT INTO multiplechoice VALUES('price x number of customers','revenue')")
 c.execute("INSERT INTO multiplechoice VALUES('total revenue of company / total industry revenue x 100','market share percantage')")
 c.execute("INSERT INTO multiplechoice VALUES('fixed cost / selling price - variable costs','break even')")
 c.execute("INSERT INTO multiplechoice VALUES('sales income- variable costs','total contibution')")
 c.execute("INSERT INTO multiplechoice VALUES('sales income - break even output','margin of safety')")
 c.execute("INSERT INTO multiplechoice VALUES('change in market share / original market size x 100','market growth')")
 c.execute("INSERT INTO multiplechoice VALUES('net profit / revenue x 100','net profit margin')")
 c.execute("INSERT INTO multiplechoice VALUES('net profit/capital employed x 100','Retrn of capital employed')")
 #c.execute("UPDATE multiplechoice")
conn.commit()

c.execute('SELECT Equation FROM multiplechoice') 
count = 0
for col in c :
   print (col)
   count = count + 1
print (count, 'Columns.')
c.close()

import random

def DrawList():
        random.shuffle(col) 
        plist = col
        button['bg'] = 'blue'
        button['fg'] = 'white'

        for item in plist:
                listbox.insert(0,item);


root = Tk()                     #This creates a window, but it won't show up
root.title("Multiple choice")
root.geometry("450x250+100+100")
labeltext = StringVar()
labeltext.set(" Question one is: " )
label3= Label(root, textvariable = labeltext,)
listbox = Listbox(root)
button = Button(root,text = "Randomise",command = DrawList)

button.pack()
listbox.pack()                  #this tells the listbox to come out
root.mainloop()                 #This command will tell the window come out
```

========================================================================

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of your `for` loop in your code, `col` assigned as your last item.
I mean,

```
lst = ["a","b","c","d"]
for x in lst: 
    pass
print (x)
>>> d
```

Also, since your `col` is only an item, `shuffle` won't do anyting.

You can create a new list then add all items to that and shuffle it.

```
new_list = [] #here is your new list. also you can create it by list comp.
count = 0
for col in c :
   print (col)
   new_list.append(col) 
   count = count + 1
print (count, 'Columns.')
c.close()

def DrawList():
        random.shuffle(new_list) 
        button['bg'] = 'blue'
        button['fg'] = 'white'

        for item in new_list:
                listbox.insert(0,item)
```